# How can I move elements to the bottom of parent considering the padding?

Tags: html, css, css-position, padding

I want to position an element **at the bottom of its parent** div, but considering its **parent bottom padding**.

See the following example:

```css
.container{
  height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
}

.toBottom{
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="toBottom">I am at the bottom</p>
</div>
```

In this example the text is right at the end of its parent, but I want it to be positioned at 100px from the bottom (because thats the padding of the parent).

---

Is this possible?
I know I could just set the bottom value of the text to 100px, but I am interested if I can somehow do that.

Comment: It's still an answer. Comments should be use for clarifying questions and are to be considered temporary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) provides tools for this.

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

p {
  background: pink; /* demo only */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="toBottom">I am at the bottom, but above padding</p>
</div>
```

If you have other content in the container, you can take a different approach.

```css
.container {
  height: 150px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: start; /* actually the default (flex-start) */
}

.toBottom {
  margin-top: auto;
}

p {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Other content</p>
  <p class="toBottom">I am at the bottom, but above padding</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to set the position of the parent and child must be in one dimension, therefore the position should not be non-static (eg relative, absolute, fixed, etc.).
you can use flexbox for this case, the default position is static.

```
.container {
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  height: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.content {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <p>I am at the bottom</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

using `justify-content: end;` so that the child is at the end of the parent